# Aggregate data from multiple excel files with the same structure

Tags: r, excel, dataset, aggregate

I prepared a survey and recipients had to fill-out an excel file. I have now a hundred of excel files with the very same structure, but different entries. For instance, for recipient_b we have:

[image]

Each excel file is named after the recipient. For instance: recipient_a_survey.xlsx; recipient_b_survey.xlsx, etc.

I would like to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
Name         birth_place birth_date domicile
recipient_a  London      21/04/1965 London
recipient_b  Manchester  19/02/1985 London
recipient_c  Glasgow     14/08/1991 Edinburgh
...
```

Is there a fancy way to do it? A way that also works with lists in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector of excel files to read using `list.files`, transpose them and bind them together in one object (`result`).

```
library(tidyverse)

file_list <- list.files('folder/of/excelfiles', pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

map_df(file_list, ~{
  df <- readxl::read_excel(.x)
  df %>%
    mutate(col = c('domicile', 'birth_date', 'birth_place')) %>%
    select(-a) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = b) %>%
    mutate(Name = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(.x)), .before = 1)
}) -> result

result
```